bootstrapping basis swap curve in quantlib
I am trying to bootstrap EUR USD Basis curve which uses FX Forward till 12 M and XCCY swaps for longer tenures.
import QuantLib as ql

calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.NYSE)

settlement_date = ql.Date(27,8,2024)
ql.Settings.instance.evaluationDate = settlement_date

sofr_rates = [
    (ql.Date(5,9,2024),0.053442),
    (ql.Date(12,9,2024),0.05351),
    (ql.Date(19,9,2024),0.05354),
    (ql.Date(30,9,2024),0.05252),
    (ql.Date(29,10,2024),0.051666),
    (ql.Date(29,11,2024),0.050677)
]

rate_helpers_sofr = []
for date, rate in  sofr_rates:
    tenor = ql.Period((date-settlement_date),ql.Days)
    rate_helper_sofr = ql.OISRateHelper (2, tenor, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate)),
                                        ql.Sofr())
    rate_helpers_sofr.append(rate_helper_sofr)

sofr_yield_curve = ql.PiecewiseLogLinearDiscount(settlement_date,rate_helpers_sofr, ql.Actual360())
sofr_curve_handle = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(sofr_yield_curve)

for date, _ in sofr_rates:
    zero_rate = sofr_yield_curve.zeroRate(date, ql.Actual360(), ql.Compounded, ql.Semiannual).rate()
    print(f"{date}: {zero_rate:0.6%}")

The output is :
September 5th, 2024: 5.412578%
September 12th, 2024: 5.412578%
September 19th, 2024: 5.415036%
September 30th, 2024: 5.386254%
October 29th, 2024: 5.250402%
November 29th, 2024: 5.147264%
After that, I input FX Forwards
joint_calendar = ql.JointCalendar(ql.TARGET(),calendar,ql.JoinHolidays)

spot_price = 1.11678

fx_price = [1.117149,
           1.117508,
           1.118427,
           1.119931]
        #   1.121434,
         #  1.122836,
          # 1.124373]

settlement_dates = [ql.Date(5,9,2024),
                   ql.Date(12,9,2024),
                   ql.Date(30,9,2024),
                   ql.Date(29,10,2024)]
                 #  ql.Date(30,12,2024),
                   #ql.Date(29,1,2025),
                    #ql.Date(28,2,2025)]

rate_helpers = [
    ql.FxSwapRateHelper(
        ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(price - spot_price)),
        ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(spot_price)),
        ql.Period(date - settlement_date, ql.Days),
        0,
        joint_calendar,
        ql.ModifiedFollowing,
        True,
        False,
        sofr_curve_handle,
    )
    for price, date in zip(fx_price, settlement_dates)
]


cross_ccy_curve = ql.PiecewiseLinearZero(settlement_date,rate_helpers,ql.Actual360())

for date in settlement_dates:
    zero_rate = cross_ccy_curve.zeroRate(date, ql.Actual360(), ql.Compounded, ql.Annual).rate()
    print(f"{date}: {zero_rate:0.6%}")

The output is :
September 5th, 2024: 4.593515%
September 12th, 2024: 4.593515%
September 30th, 2024: 4.443295%
October 29th, 2024: 4.186313%
I have few questions:

for USD SOFR the first two zero rates are same even though the market rates are different.
there is less difference in zero rates for USD SOFR but the difference in XCCY zero rates is very high. How can I possibly reduce the differences?

